# Как на питоне составить регулярное выражение для таких выражений "45 . 2 руб за кг" или "45 , 2 за кг"

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Как на питоне составить регулярное выражение для таких выражений "45 . 2 руб за кг" или "45 , 2 за кг", чтобы получилось "45.2 руб за кг"?

Comment: Почему именно регулярные выражения? `text = text.replace(' , ', ',').replace(' . ', '.')`

Comment: `"45 . 2 руб за кг".replace(" . ", ".").replace(" , ", ".")` . WiktorStribiżew, забавно получилось :)

Comment: А если точка или запятая еще и между словами будет? Мне ее трогать не надо "45 . 2 руб за , кг"

Comment: составить можно руками, полагаю

Answer (score 0):

А, разобрался:

```
message = "32 . 5 р за кг"
incoming_text = re.sub(r'(\d+)\s([\.,]?)\s(\d+)', r'\1.\3', message)
```

> `"32.5 р за кг"`